@InjectModel decorator is not worked with typescript higher versions than 5.1 in nestJs
I'm encountering an issue with ESLint in my NestJS application. Here are the relevant details:-

Node.js version: 20.12.1
TypeScript version: 5.4
Jest version: 29.4
In my application, I'm using the @InjectModel() decorator to inject the mongoose model in both my service class and repository class. I've registered the schema using the forFeature method inside my module as shown below:

//trips.module.ts
import { LocationsSchema, LocationsSchemaName } from '@transporter-asia/schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: TripsSchemaName,
        schema: TripsSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [TripsController],
  providers: [TripsService, TripsRepository],
  exports: [TripsService],
})
export class TripsModule {}

//trips.repository.ts
import { LocationsDocument, LocationsSchemaName } from '@transporter-asia/schema';

@Injectable()
export class TripsRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(TripsSchemaName)
    private tripsDocumentModel: Model<TripsDocument>,
  ) {}
  // Other functions...
}

While this setup works fine and the application executes without any issues, ESLint is throwing the following warning:
Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'.ts(1239)
This warning seems to be related to how @InjectModel() is being used. However, it doesn't affect the execution of the application.
The problem arises when I try to write test cases for the repository class (trips.repository.spec.ts). Here's a snippet of the test file:
//trips.repository.spec.ts
import { LocationsDocument, LocationsSchemaName } from '@transporter-asia/schema';

describe('TripsRepository', () => {
    const tripMockDataModel = {
        findById: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        find: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        findOne: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        aggregate: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        save: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        findOneAndUpdate: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      };
  let tripsRepository: TripsRepository;
  let tripsDocumentModel: any;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TripsRepository,
        { 
            provide: getModelToken(TripsSchemaName), 
            useValue: tripMockDataModel
        },
    }).compile();

    tripsRepository = module.get<TripsRepository>(TripsRepository);
    tripsDocumentModel = module.get<Model<TripsDocument>>(
        getModelToken(TripsSchemaName)
      );
  });
}

I don't encounter this issue with TypeScript versions below 4.9. Can someone help me understand why this warning is occurring and how I can resolve it?

You didn't mention version of Nestjs. Is it up-to-date? There are already some people in issues with same problem.

@Jax-p Nestjs version is 10.3.7

in vs code ctrl + shift + v and type typescript version in the dropdown menu  select use workspace version
